# Get JSON distant file and write/store a file with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I search how to write a file with angularjs, after get it in json. I have already the json file in my folder, but with onclick, users can manually update it with the new content and overwrite the same file. How to write it ? (i don't ask the get distant file part).

I need locastorage functions ? it's for android application, so which storage i must use ?

Comment: This question is pretty confusing and not very clear on what you are trying to do. Can you please post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write files with javascript. You would need to pass the data to PHP or nodejs (aka a server side language) that has access to your filesystem. Javascript is client facing, so it doesn't know anything about the filesystem on the server it is running.